# How to get URL rewrites working correctly?

Tags: url-rewrite, apache

When trying the URL rewrites, all the links break in a clean install of Magento 1.9.0. I would rather have `mysite.com/category/category` instead of `mysite.com/index.php/category/category`. How do you get this configured correctly? I already have the correct settings under the apache config.

I also don't know enough about Magento yet, so I don't know what data to provide. Anything else needed and requested I will provide to help get this issue resolved.

Answer (score 3):

Your .htaccess file is not loaded or does not contain the rewrite section and/or your vhost file from apache does not contain the correct section.

For conf file

```
 <Directory /home/path/to/html>
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
</Directory>
```

For .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

    #RewriteBase /magento/

############################################
## uncomment next line to enable light API calls processing

#    RewriteRule ^api/([a-z][0-9a-z_]+)/?$ api.php?type=$1 [QSA,L]

############################################
## rewrite API2 calls to api.php (by now it is REST only)

    RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]

############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
    RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]

############################################
## redirect for mobile user agents

    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobiledirectoryhere/.*$
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobiledirectoryhere/ [L,R=302]

############################################
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```